# Delayed displaying of image view objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, imageview

I am trying to keep my app to one view controller so i dont have to pass information back and forth. First the user uses text fields to fill in information and then my program processes it and displays labels on an image. Is it possible to have an image view hidden until a button is clicked and then bring the image forward and display the image view on top of the text fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
imageView.alpha = 0; // Not visible
imageView.alpha = 1; // Visible
```

You can put it under obe of your `UIButton` action.

In order for it to be on top of everything just drag the image view to be at the lowest level inside the interface builder.